# Why are months in my date slicer repeating? How do I fix it?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The months on my date slicers are repeating regardless of the column I use as a value. How do I fix this?

[image: Visualisations]

[image: Formats are different]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Slicer will display distinct values in a column. If there are duplicate values displaying in a Slicer, it is very likely that some spaces or non-printable characters before or after the values.

Trim the columns in Power Query then apply the slicer, it will display distinct values only